# How to delete all BlueOcean GitHub tokens from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

I love how the BlueOcean plugin makes it easy to create pipelines based on a Jenkinsfile. But I was using my account for testing and now would like to switch to the proper one. However, when I get to the pipeline creation it remembers me and I can see that it has access to the organizations and repositories from my account, even though I've deleted the pipelines/repositories created on BlueOcean.

The only [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187250/jenkins-blue-ocean-change-github-access-token) I found related to this did not help me because I don't see anything close to "blueocean" on the credentials page. Is there another way? Can't seem to find any documentation on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Your Jenkins UI, click on the peoples section on left side.
2. Then select the user for which you want to delete the token.
3. Then click on credentials on the left side, now you will be able to see existing token for blue ocean domain.

I hope this helps, in case of any queries feel free to contact.

Comment: BlueOcean does not allow to remove the token from tu UI